# Is is possible to use Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server in .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: owin, openid-connect, adfs

While using `Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` in 4.5 framework facing the below error :

> error CS1061: 'IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'UseOpenIdConnectServer' and no accessible extension method
>   'UseOpenIdConnectServer' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)`

Can anyone suggest a way to overcome this error?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer and vote it as helpful. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. 

To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` version 2.00, the dependencies are
[image]

If you are using `Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` version 1.1.0, the dependencies are
[image]